# Chrome extension addEventListener not working correct

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My extension has a popup window with one button. When this button clicked, extension create a new tab. But when I clicked on browser-action button, new tab is creating without opening a popup window.

Manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "myApp",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "myApp",



"permissions": [
"tabs",
"notifications"
],
"browser_action": {
"default_icon":"rLogo.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html"
}
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:250px;height:150px">
<input type = "button" id="open">
</div>
<script src = "popup.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function openRoom(url)
{
    chrome.tabs.create({url:url});      
};  
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {      
var link = document.getElementById('open');
 link.addEventListener('click',openRoom("https://www.google.com"));
 });
```

Comment: `openRoom("https://www.google.com")` is not a function, nor a reference to one, it is an example of a _function-call_. Try replacing it with `function(){openRoom("https://www.google.com");}`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
link.addEventListener('click', openRoom("https://www.google.com"));
```

With this:

```
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    openRoom("https://www.google.com");
});
```

Hope this works!